# Database Connectivity Issue in window

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1:09 PM
WARNING: could not load hiredis extension, using (slower) pure Ruby implementation.
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds (LoadError) from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in` require'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:23:in `rescue in <main>' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:22:in` '
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in` each'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in` each'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:187:in` require'
from C:/Azure/RiskNet/config/application.rb:13:in `<main>' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in` require_application!'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:101:in` perform'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in` perform'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in` '
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>' C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in` require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/3.0/tiny_tds (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0-x64-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:21:in` '
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in` each'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in` each'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:187:in` require'
from C:/Azure/RiskNet/config/application.rb:13:in `<main>' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in` require_application!'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:101:in` perform'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in` perform'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in` '
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require' from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'
from bin/rails:4:in `'

I am trying to connect vm server to local after install tiny_tds gem and try to run rails console still getting this error

Comment: Please construct your question. What do you try to do, your code samples etc.

Comment: I want to connect vm database to local in window system.